# Minimize the variance of a three-security portfolio

Tags: variance, optimization

I have three securities whose variance covariance matrix looks like this:

```
        DE5   FR10   IT15
DE5  0.0376 0.0350 0.0243
FR10 0.0350 0.0658 0.0658
IT15 0.0243 0.0658 0.1335
```

How do I weight each of the three to minimize variance of the package, excluding the (0, 0, 0) solution. I don't mind "going short" IE, a mixture of positive and negative coefficients.

Can this be done with regression? I suspect not as weights will depend on which variable is chosen as dependent.

Is there a straightforward linear-algebra way of doing this without bringing in heavyweight quadratic programming package? I have many of these to do.

Ideally I'd like some code in R.

Comment: Traditionally, one would use quadratic programming rather than regression.

Comment: @John but will regression work? I have over 500k of these to do and I know the regression routines in R are highly optimized. The thing is if I use regression, which variable do I choose as the dependent variable? Does it matter? See I think I get a problem because depending on which variable I use as dependent, I'll get different solutions even after scaling.

Comment: First, you need to clearly determine/state all the constraints on the weights. Do they need to sum to 1 (not just that at least one is non-zero)? You "don't mind" shorting, but is there a constraint on magnitude of shorting. e.g.,  is weight < -1 allowed? Etc. Then you can worry about solution methods.  Do actual problems to be solved only involve 3 securities, or are they larger?

Comment: @ThomasBrowne Under some conditions, a quadratic optimization is equivalent to a regression, but as Mark L. Stone notes the types of constraints are important. I would refer you to "The Sampling Error in Estimates of Mean-Variance Efficient Portfolio Weights" by Mark Britten-Jones as a classic source. I'm sure there are others. Also, a good quadratic optimization library, even in R, should be calling C/Fortran code for the best performance. You can do them in parallel to increase speed.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone There is only one single constraint: at least one of the series must have a non-zero weight, given upfront. Because otherwise the optimizer will just give me three zeros. There is no constraint on the sum of the coefficients. And yes, I may generalize to larger problems.

Comment: @John I'll take a look at that source, many thanks. Also your (and Mark L. Stone)s' opinion on the answer below would be useful.

Comment: Why not just buy one cent worth 9or whatever the minimum quantity) of the lowest variance security? It is very unusual to not require a normalized (to 1) sum of weights.

Comment: @ThomasBrowne The constraint "at least one of the series must have a non-zero weight", by itself, would actually be hard to implement. It would require mixed integer quadratic programming because it would need a binary variable in there to handle the "at least one" part. Mark L. Stone's point is also valid that you could just have the bare minimum of the lowest variance security. You need something else going on beyond just that constraint. If the weights sum to 1, then at least one security is guaranteed to have a positive weight, that may be bigger than 100%.

Comment: @John - okay what I meant was that I wanted the minimum variance portfolio of all three securities, while excluding the (0, 0, 0) solution. So either you specify one _specific_ security to have non-zero (any arbitrary number), which will necessarily bound the other two since otherwise we we are not minimizing. It is basically equivalent to saying "sum of weights = 1" for example. My working was inaccurate. I have changed the question.

Comment: @ThomasBrowne I'm not sure we are getting through...maybe instead of thinking about it in weights, think about in terms of shares purchased. The lowest volatility portfolio is buying one share in the stock with the lowest expected volatility. You can instead think about the portfolio investing a certain dollar amount (the total of price times quantity of shares). This is equivalent to the constraint that the weights sum to 1. Moreover, if you add the constraint that the weights sum to 1, then even if you allow shorting at least one variable has a non-zero weight. Something has to be positive.

Comment: @John, actually what I am trying to do is, given three securities, which two securities are the best hedge for the third, _without knowing in advance_ which is the "body" (~"belly")" security in the butterfly and which are the wings.

Comment: @ThomasBrowne With three securities it's relatively easy...just do the optimization three times, constraining one security's weight to be 1 in each of the optimizations. This would not be a good solution with a larger portfolio, but I think would work here.

Answer (score 3):

This is a well-known finance problem. If the constraints are in the form

$
w_i \geq Const\ \ \ \rm{or}\ \ \ w_i \leq Const
$

the closed-form solution (formula) does not exist. You have to use iterative optimization methods. However, your constraint

$
w_i \neq Const
$

has measure 0 and is likely to be *nonbinding*. You can solve the unconstrained problem using formula

$
w = \frac{\Omega^{-1}\rm{1}}{\rm{1^{T}}\Omega^{-1}\rm{1}}
$

where $\Omega$ is the covariance matrix and $\rm{1}$ is the vectors of 1's... Then you can see that all the weights are non-zero and happily conclude that the constrained solution is the same as the unconstrained one.

Please note: the formula above gives the absolutely minimum-variance portfolio assuming

$\ \ \ $1) there is not riskless asset (cash account or treasury bond),

$\ \ \ $2) you are fine with any expected return.

The formula for the minimum-variance portfolio assuming a specific expected return is somewhat different.